# Using fdesign with filtfilt - no phase

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to figure out a way to use filters by fdesign with filtfilt in order not to have additional phase introduced by the filter.  I found the following article and it adequately addresses the issue for low pass filter.  See below:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/260604

How about high, band, and stop pass cases?  Do I have to use a different syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed that the same syntax works for all types of filters such as lowpass, highpass, etc.